# json value in php using json_encode

Tags: php, json

I have the below `php` code which outputs me a `json` array from freebase api.

```
<?php
public function search($query, $filter = '', $start = 0, $limit = 10, $exact = 'false'){

  if(!empty($query)){
      $service_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=';
      $append = "[{\"id\":\"$query\",\"key\":[{\"namespace\":\"/wikipedia/en_title\",\"*\":null}]}]";
      $url = $service_url. $append;
      return json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
  }
}
}
$freebase = new Freebase();
$result = $freebase->search('/m/03np_7');
$obj = json_encode($result);
echo $obj;
?>
```

My `$obj` output is as below.

```
{"result":[{"key":[{"namespace":"\/wikipedia\/en_title","value":"University_of_Texas_at_Arlington","type":"\/type\/key"}],"id":"\/m\/03np_7"}]}
```

I am trying to get the value field alone using `php`. I tried `json_decode` but it was saying it accepts only string and I have an array. How can I get the value alone from the `Json_encode`?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `$result` is an array and `$obj` is a string.

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant the field "value" inside "key".

Comment: http://codepad.org/Dv98uzHY

Comment: `$obj = json_encode($result); echo $obj;` Don't re-encode it in JSON. You already have it in an array. Just work with `$result` directly if you want to extract a value from it.